# Flutter google map current location to center point of screen

Tags: flutter, google-maps, mobile, widget, geocoding

I am creating a flutter application and using google map inside it, I need to get the position information of center of screen, therefore, I putted an Icon on the middle of screen using center property and I get the position information of middle of screen using below getMarkerPosition() function. everything is going well.
**my problem is when application start I need the center Icon start on the current position or the current position be equal to center of the screen.**

```
Future<void> getMarkerPosition() async {

  double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width *
      MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
  double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
      MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;


  double middleX = screenWidth / 2;
  double middleY = screenHeight / 2;

  ScreenCoordinate screenCoordinate = ScreenCoordinate(x: middleX.round(), y: middleY.round());

  LatLng middlePoint = await googleMapController!.getLatLng(screenCoordinate);
  
}
```

```
    return Scaffold(
        key: sKey,
        drawer: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
          child: Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              canvasColor: Colors.black,
            ),
            child: MyDrawer(
              name: userName,
              phone: userPhone,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              GoogleMap(
                  key: containerKey,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottomPaddding),
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  initialCameraPosition: _iraq,
                  polylines: polyLineSet,
                  markers: markerSet,
                  circles: circleSet,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    _controller.complete(controller);
                    googleMapController = controller;

                    locateUserPosition();
                    setState(() {
                      bottomPaddding = 120;
                    });
                    //for black theme google map
                  },
                  onCameraIdle: () {
                    if (stateRequest == "start") {
                    } else if (stateRequest == "source") {
                      getMarkerPosition();
                    }
                  },
                  

              Center(
                  child: IconButton(
                    iconSize: 30,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.place,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )),

              Positioned(
                  top: 10,
                  left: 10,
                  child: RawMaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (openNavigationDrawer) {
                        sKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
                      } else {
                        // restart-refresh app proggramatically.
                        SystemNavigator.pop();
                      }
                    },
                    elevation: 1.0,
                    fillColor: Colors.white38,
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    child: Icon(
                      openNavigationDrawer ? Icons.menu : Icons.close,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                  )),

              // UI for searching location
              startRequestContainer(),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

[Screen shot of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUpLm.png)

**I need the the current position be equal to the center point of screen.**

Answer (score -1):

i will suggest 2 way

1. use camera animate function to get your location in center

mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude), 14));

2. use [Location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package to get user location & put a custom marker on it.

Comment: Actually, I tried the both ways, the animated camera move the camera to current user location but it's not exactly on the center of screen, and the second way is also not work as I am using an Icon in the center of the screen